# Detecting Worksheet Changes AFTER Ado .CopyFromRecordSet event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that connects to a SQL DB using Ado and will upload the contents of the database into the excel sheet. I have that part working well. Now I want to check to see if a cell changes after the data has been inserted. Here is my code in the Worksheeet_Change so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
Dim KeyCells As range
Set KeyCells = range("Table:Environment")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    range("CleanHeaders").ClearContents
    range("CleanDates").ClearContents
    Call SQL_Connect.connect
    Call Data_Download.header_download
    Call Data_Download.download_data
    Call SQL_Connect.close_connection
End If
Dim DataRng As range, roww As Long
Dim rng As range
Set DataRng = Intersect(range("DataStart:Z10000"), Target)
If Not DataRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each rng In DataRng
        roww = rng.Row
        If Not rng.Value = " " Then
        Cells(roww, "AA").Value = "1"
        Else
        Cells(roww, "AA").Value = "0"
        End If
        Next
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

To give you a quick run down, here is what is going on in the code. The first part focuses on a specific box in the sheet. When it is changed, it calls a connection, downloads headers and data, then closes connection. Like I said, this part runs fine and I have no issues with it. The next part is my attempt to check for changes in these cells. The issue is, every time I clean a table or upload new data to it, it thinks it is a change and will put 1's in all rows. **I want to detect these changes AFTER the data has been downloaded to the sheet. How would I go about fixing this to properly achieve this?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any event that runs on changes risks activating itself. To prevent this from happening, disable events while running the sub using [EnableEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim KeyCells As range
Set KeyCells = range("Table:Environment")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    range("CleanHeaders").ClearContents
    range("CleanDates").ClearContents
    Call SQL_Connect.connect
    Call Data_Download.header_download
    Call Data_Download.download_data
    Call SQL_Connect.close_connection
End If
Dim DataRng As range, roww As Long
Dim rng As range
Set DataRng = Intersect(range("DataStart:Z10000"), Target)
If Not DataRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each rng In DataRng
        roww = rng.Row
        If Not rng.Value = " " Then
        Cells(roww, "AA").Value = "1"
        Else
        Cells(roww, "AA").Value = "0"
        End If
        Next
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Application.EnableEvents = True` be placed above`If Not DataRng Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: @tokyo_north by making it conditional, you are playing with fire. A recursing event will outright crash the host (Excel), not just raise a run-time error.

Comment: That would activate the sub itself, as that piece of code changes cell values. You wouldn't want to do that, as mentioned by Mathieu